# How can i change the position of modal in ionic3?

Tags: css, typescript, user-interface, ionic-framework, ionic3

[image: Sample Reference of Present modal]I am using modal in ionic-3, and the target devices are tablets.
want to show the modal on left side of screen so is there any way to change the position and size of ionic-3 modal popup?

Comment: Add reference design.

Comment: I want to shift this modal to left of the screen and need to modify the dimensions but not able to modify by by applying css  on modal because the modal is whole ionic page itself

Comment: Did you try...?

Comment: yes i have tried that and its working fine, if we copy the cssfrom scss file in custom css file with targeted modification that also works

Answer (score 2):

Pass `cssClass` while creating `modal`.

```
 let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPage, {data: data}, {cssClass: 'custom-modal' });
```

Apply CSS to the class in `app.scss`

```
.select-modal {
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
   padding: 20% 10%  !important;
}
```

As per your requirement, adjust padding.